# Sending Request with iOS - Express answers with 304 HTTPCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, node.js, express

i am developing a App for iPad.
I'm using express and a restful approach as a backend.
Express on the route `GET /baumkontrollen` should respond as the following:

```
exports.getAll = function(req, res) {
    if(req.cookies.email) {
        pq.getBaumkontrollen(function(rows) {
            res.send(rows);
        });
    }
    else {
        res.send(400, 'Sie sind nicht eingelogt.');
    }
};
```

but on the console i get: `GET /baumkontrollen 304 23ms`

I'm using an iPad for Requests. There i do it like this:

```
NSMutableString *serverString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:BKServerURL];
    [serverString appendString:@"baumkontrollen"];

    serverNSURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:serverString];
    req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:serverNSURL];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [req addValue:cookies forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];

    serverConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

The variable `cookies` is of type NSArray.
Why do i get an 304 HTTP Status Code?

[This](http://pastebin.com/JZHb6zag) is the Request from an iPad.

[This](http://pastebin.com/dXexXSuV) is from my Browser, it just works i get a 200 :/

Comment: If you debug it with charles proxy you can compare what's different about the two requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by adding this line to the request:

```
[req setValue:@"no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cache-Control"];
```